# Words and buttons are falling outside the new dupe window on mobile, rescue them!

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, mobile-web

I went to one of my question with a dupe vote pending and saw this nightmare:

> [image]

The button "That solved my problem" and phrase "No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how." are falling out of the window.

Was this window attacked by Zalgo?

Comment: You'd think it might be a little easier to see the problem if half the screen wasn't covered in red...

Comment: … But you'd be wrong!

Comment: @door that's obligatory freehand. And I clarified a bit.

Comment: What does "HALP çAVemi NOObOI:" mean?

Comment: @A.L HALP, SAVE ME,  NOOOOO!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of these days I'll remember to test the mobile views...

Fix coming in the next build. Thanks for the report!